# How can I save and read information from java to XML using XmlJsonParser?

Tags: java, xml, file

```
import parser.XmlJsonParser;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    XmlJsonParser parser = new XmlJsonParser();
    GradeList grades = new GradeList(15);
    grades = parser.toXml(grades, "grades.xml");

    System.out.println("File: " + );
  }
}
```

What I did so far is I tried to create an array Object and save the information on an .xml file, but IntelliJ shows a red underline under .toXml in the code snippet. Can you show me how an .xml file stores data with XmlJsonParser?

Comment: Did you write XmlJsonParser? Does it have a public method toXML?

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for your question. We'll need to know a bit more before we can properly help you. What is XmlJsonParser and where does it come from? It isn't a standard part of java so unless you can give us that info, we probably can't help you. If IntelliJ is highlighting the code, then it is either because it is configured badly or because the library in question doesn't exist. We can't tell which yet. A quick search for your class returns no known implementations, so we're a bit lost without more info from you.